# How to use the -flatten and -page in imageMagick to overlap one image on another image with specific offset value

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

MY program use imageMagick to resize actual image by keeping the aspect ratio and adding the smaller marker image on the actual image

First I have keep the height 150 and width would be float to keep the aspect ratio and later I am finding the relative point where I need to keep the marker pointer
Below is the code what I have use

def originalImageAspectRatio = Integer.parseInt(params.imageWidth)/Integer.parseInt(params.imageHeight)

def width = 150 * originalImageAspectRatio

```
        IMOperation op = new IMOperation();
        op.addImage("-")
        op.quality(50)
        op.strip();
        op.autoOrient();
        op.addRawArgs("-resize",width+"x"+150+"^")
        op.page(0,0,(int)relativePoint.x,(int)relativePoint.y)
        op.addImage(markerIcon)
        op.flatten()
        op.addImage("jpeg:-")
```

Here I want to create a thumbnail image and the marker pointer should be same as the original image contain so for that I am finding the relative point of x and y

But the image is resizing properly and also keeping the aspect ration but the marker pointer is not coming at the same coordinate point where I have added in the large image